# why one would put function defination in .h fie?

Tags: c, gstreamer

i am reffiring one gstreamer plugin code and i came to know in .h file they have written some following type function in .h file

```
static inline GstByteReader *
gst_ebml_read_br (GstEbmlRead * ebml)
{
  g_return_val_if_fail (ebml->readers, NULL);
  g_return_val_if_fail (ebml->readers->len, NULL);

  return &(g_array_index (ebml->readers,
          GstEbmlMaster, ebml->readers->len - 1).br);
}
```

you can see here its source 
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/coverage/lcov/gst-plugins-good/gst/matroska/ebml-read.h.gcov.html

**Edit : all function in that files are static inline**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C compilers aren't necessarily capable of inlining functions at link time. Therefore, if you actually want to give the compiler the best chance of inlining the function there must be a definition of the function in every TU that uses it. So it needs to be defined in the header file. `inline` allows the program to have multiple definitions of a function in different TUs.

Additionally, this function is marked `static`, giving it internal linkage and meaning that each TU has its own separate copy of the function.

Comment: then why not to just remove static tag ? if we remove static tag and define this func in any .c file will give the same result ?

Comment: The static tag could be removed, provided that nothing in the function body requires that the function has internal linkage (see 6.7.4/3 for what those things are). Defining the function in only one `.c` file would contradict "there must be a definition of the function in every TU that uses it" - firstly it will prevent it being inlined at compile-time (although a smart enough linker might inline it at link time), and in any case it's a requirement that functions marked `inline` must be defined in the TU they're used (6.7.4/6).

Answer (score 1):

In order for `inline` to work, the code has to be available at the point where it is used, so it has to be in the header.

Comment: then why not to just remove static  tag ? if we remove static tag  and define this func  in any .c file will give the same result ?